Inventor of the Semitic stem type naming system
I am learning about stem derivation in Arabic. Reading the Wikipedia article "Derived stem", I was curious regarding the naming rationale for the stem types ("G", "Gt", "D", ...). Apparently, G comes from "Grundstamm", so I searched a bit using German.
There is a 1906 article by Arthur Ungnad (citation below). He credited Fritz Hommel with a unified stem naming system, claiming that Hommel had used numbers as a shorthand. He then essentially proposes the modern short-hand system of upper and lowercase letters.
Is he the first person known to have used/proposed this system?
Ungnad, A. (1906). Die Bezeichnung der Verbalstämme im Semitischen. Orientalistische Literaturzeitung, 9(1-6), 23-24. https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1524/olzg.1906.9.16.23/html

Ungnad pretty much states that he invented this system and I do not see any evidence for the contrary.
